# manytoone and bidirectional in hibernate annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

in Hibernate manytoone and bidirectional relationship, in childentity table, list of rows are getting inserted but parent_id is not getting inserted.
 The code which i have used are given below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class ParentEntity
{
...
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ChildEntity> children;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class ChildEntity
{
...
@Id
@Column(name = "child_id")
private Long id;
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable=false)
private ParentEntity parent;
...
```

}

In this scenario, I am getting the error called, parent_id should not be null in DAO class.

If I remove the nullable = false then child entities are getting inserted in database, But there is no parent_id.

Comment: please add code showing how you set the relation between the entites. It is not enough to add a child entity to the list in the parent.

Comment: can you update the question with the code you are using to save.

Comment: have you managed to fix it? is there sth unclear?

Answer (score 0):

With all JPA providers including Hibernate, the application is responsible for setting the correct references on both ends of the relation. In your case it should look sth like this:

```
parent.getChildren().add(child);
child.setParent(parent);
```